# use of unresolved identifier 'info'

Tags: ios, swift2

I am trying to display an image, from a library, but keep getting the error "use of unresolved identifier 'info'", under function imagePickerController, where "if let image = info[......."

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var imagePickerView: UIImageView!
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{
        self.imagePickerView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        self.imagePickerView.image = image
    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func pickerButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    self.imagePicker.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any variable named `info`, maybe you ment `editingInfo`?

I think your function should be like this:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
    if let info = editingInfo, image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{
        self.imagePickerView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        self.imagePickerView.image = image
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. I believe the new xcode changed the info to editing info. I can be wrong:)

Comment: Glad to know. Please mark this answer as a solution for other users to know your problem is already solved.